# Save whole PyQt4 QWidget window with matplotlib plots to a png file

Tags: python, matplotlib, qt4, pyqt4, qpixmap

I'm trying to capture and save to a file whole QWidget window with several matplotlib plots.

I'm adding matplotlib axes to the widget as below:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas

app   = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
win   = QtGui.QWidget()
grid  = QtGui.QGridLayout()

fig  = plt.figure()
axs  = fig.add_subplot(111)
axs.plot([1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8])
canv = FigureCanvas(fig)   
canv.setMaximumHeight(100) 
grid.addWidget(canv, 0, 0)
grid.addWidget(QtGui.QLabel('Label'),1,0)
win.setLayout(grid)
win.show()
win.setFixedSize(150,100)
```

Output window looks ok (output.png - from external print-screen app).

But when I try to capture the output window to the QPixmap object by:

```
    sshot = QtGui.QPixmap.grabWidget(ow)
    sshot.save('tmp.png')
```

tmp.jpg doesn't contain matplotlib figure (tmp.png).

Even when I try to capture whole desktop:

```
    sshot = QtGui.QPixmap.grabWindow(app.desktop().winId())
    sshot.save('desktop.png')
```

the matplotlib figure is empty (desktop.png).

[Three screen-shots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dtuks.png)

How can I capture the whole window without blank matplotlib figures?

Cheers,
Pawel